# Not able to access 192.168.x.x machine from Android emulator

Tags: android, http, emulation, subnet

I have two machines connected to a wi-fi router.
One gets the ip as 192.168.1.2 and other gets 192.168.1.3
I have a web server running on 3 machine. I need to access the php files on that machine from 2 machine. But unable to get that.
Any idea why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the Android emulator can only access localhost via 10.0.2.2, thus there is no way to access other IP addresses unless you use a real device.